# Can I move a one drive RAID 0 array on a PERC 6 to another server?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, perc6

We have a Dell Poweredge 2970 with a PERC 6/i RAID controller. We have a one drive RAID 0 array (we wanted to add the drive as a JBOD but the PERC forces you to create an array to access it from the PERC). Can we take the one drive RAID 0 and move it to a new server (one that doesn't have a PERC)? Since there's only one drive in the "array" there's no striping going on...the only issue would seem to be if the PERC has some metadata on the drive that would prevent Windows from reading it.

Does anyone have any experience with this scenario?

Comment: Whatever you do get a backup first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

moving drives between PERCs is easy:
1. make sure the config on the destination controller is cleared
2. power dest. host down, insert the drive
3. power on, go into PERC bios, and find the option to import "foreign config"

If a foreign config isn't detected, simply create a new raid-0 on the drive, and make sure you do not allow the new array to initialise (that will wipe it). With no initialization, you'll get a new raid-0 with all you data in it.

Comment: We're going to find out if this is going to work later this week. If it works I'll give you the answer for this question.

Comment: I've done this too many times to even count, but if you're still not sure, you definitely want to have a tested backup handy, and possibly call Dell support and ask them to walk you through this procedure